# Awk to Add Average FX Rates per Year

Tags: awk

I am trying to add to my Awk code (below) to Add Average FX Rates per Year to my data (or the Average FX Rates per Partial Year if only partial year info.).
See last 2 rows of Output file for examples (with not-accurate, sample number data).

The missing piece is how to get the averages of the correct rows.  Any ideas as to how to calculate this information using Awk?

INPUT FILE

```
remove1
MMM YYYY    USD/GBP CAD/GBP EUR/GBP JPY/GBP CHF/GBP AUD/GBP HKD/GBP NZD/GBP KRW/GBP MXN/GBP
Jan 2017    1.2348  1.6288  1.1611  141.81  1.2441  1.6537  9.5778  1.7318  1457.1  26.447
Feb 2017    1.2494  1.6380  1.1732  141.08  1.2508  1.6304  9.6953  1.7283  1426.1  25.369
Mar 2017    1.2346  1.6528  1.1549  139.39  1.2365  1.6199  9.5882  1.7626  1399.4  23.802
Apr 2017    1.2644  1.7001  1.1797  139.31  1.2653  1.6791  9.8297  1.8151  1435.4  23.750
May 2017    1.2920  1.7580  1.1698  145.03  1.2752  1.7379  10.0605 1.8594  1455.2  24.247
Jun 2017    1.2806  1.7030  1.1399  142.05  1.2396  1.6940  9.9874  1.7714  1449.3  23.225
Jul 2017    1.2995  1.6488  1.1272  146.03  1.2480  1.6652  10.1480 1.7658  1471.9  23.137
Aug 2017    1.2951  1.6324  1.0963  142.18  1.2499  1.6362  10.1299 1.7740  1465.3  23.052
Sep 2017    1.3338  1.6383  1.1198  147.83  1.2843  1.6735  10.4205 1.8381  1511.3  23.785
Oct 2017    1.3200  1.6638  1.1229  149.08  1.2966  1.6953  10.3033 1.8758  1494.6  24.849
Nov 2017    1.3230  1.6893  1.1262  149.16  1.3113  1.7358  10.3270 1.9211  1455.8  25.020
Dec 2017    1.3404  1.7118  1.1328  151.38  1.3234  1.7540  10.4727 1.9256  1453.7  25.667
Jan 2018    1.3825  1.7180  1.1328  153.24  1.3276  1.7374  10.8108 1.9027  1474.9  26.137
Feb 2018    1.3962  1.7571  1.1312  150.76  1.3059  1.7748  10.9210 1.9116  1507.0  26.037
Mar 2018    1.3973  1.8070  1.1329  148.25  1.3243  1.8003  10.9564 1.9256  1497.2  26.016
Apr 2018    1.4077  1.7922  1.1468  151.49  1.3630  1.8321  11.0477 1.9432  1504.6  25.874
May 2018    1.3466  1.7335  1.1396  147.62  1.3427  1.7898  10.5694 1.9367  1450.5  26.298
Jun 2018    1.3287  1.7443  1.1380  146.26  1.3154  1.7732  10.4268 1.9147  1455.1  26.977
Jul 2018    1.3170  1.7292  1.1267  146.83  1.3098  1.7783  10.3352 1.9390  1479.2  24.969
Aug 2018    1.2849  1.6791  1.1182  142.59  1.2771  1.7520  10.0874 1.9298  1446.0  24.191
remove2
```

OUTPUT NEEDED

```
YYYY/MM|MMM YYYY|MMM|YYYY|USD/GBP|CAD/GBP|EUR/GBP|JPY/GBP|CHF/GBP|AUD/GBP|HKD/GBP|NZD/GBP|KRW/GBP|MXN/GBP||||||||
2017/01|1 Jan 2017|Jan|2017|1.2348|1.6288|1.1611|141.81|1.2441|1.6537|9.5778|1.7318|1457.1|26.447||||||||
2017/02|1 Feb 2017|Feb|2017|1.2494|1.6380|1.1732|141.08|1.2508|1.6304|9.6953|1.7283|1426.1|25.369||||||||
2017/03|1 Mar 2017|Mar|2017|1.2346|1.6528|1.1549|139.39|1.2365|1.6199|9.5882|1.7626|1399.4|23.802||||||||
2017/04|1 Apr 2017|Apr|2017|1.2644|1.7001|1.1797|139.31|1.2653|1.6791|9.8297|1.8151|1435.4|23.750||||||||
2017/05|1 May 2017|May|2017|1.2920|1.7580|1.1698|145.03|1.2752|1.7379|10.0605|1.8594|1455.2|24.247||||||||
2017/06|1 Jun 2017|Jun|2017|1.2806|1.7030|1.1399|142.05|1.2396|1.6940|9.9874|1.7714|1449.3|23.225||||||||
2017/07|1 Jul 2017|Jul|2017|1.2995|1.6488|1.1272|146.03|1.2480|1.6652|10.1480|1.7658|1471.9|23.137||||||||
2017/08|1 Aug 2017|Aug|2017|1.2951|1.6324|1.0963|142.18|1.2499|1.6362|10.1299|1.7740|1465.3|23.052||||||||
2017/09|1 Sep 2017|Sep|2017|1.3338|1.6383|1.1198|147.83|1.2843|1.6735|10.4205|1.8381|1511.3|23.785||||||||
2017/10|1 Oct 2017|Oct|2017|1.3200|1.6638|1.1229|149.08|1.2966|1.6953|10.3033|1.8758|1494.6|24.849||||||||
2017/11|1 Nov 2017|Nov|2017|1.3230|1.6893|1.1262|149.16|1.3113|1.7358|10.3270|1.9211|1455.8|25.020||||||||
2017/12|1 Dec 2017|Dec|2017|1.3404|1.7118|1.1328|151.38|1.3234|1.7540|10.4727|1.9256|1453.7|25.667||||||||
2018/01|1 Jan 2018|Jan|2018|1.3825|1.7180|1.1328|153.24|1.3276|1.7374|10.8108|1.9027|1474.9|26.137||||||||
2018/02|1 Feb 2018|Feb|2018|1.3962|1.7571|1.1312|150.76|1.3059|1.7748|10.9210|1.9116|1507.0|26.037||||||||
2018/03|1 Mar 2018|Mar|2018|1.3973|1.8070|1.1329|148.25|1.3243|1.8003|10.9564|1.9256|1497.2|26.016||||||||
2018/04|1 Apr 2018|Apr|2018|1.4077|1.7922|1.1468|151.49|1.3630|1.8321|11.0477|1.9432|1504.6|25.874||||||||
2018/05|1 May 2018|May|2018|1.3466|1.7335|1.1396|147.62|1.3427|1.7898|10.5694|1.9367|1450.5|26.298||||||||
2018/06|1 Jun 2018|Jun|2018|1.3287|1.7443|1.1380|146.26|1.3154|1.7732|10.4268|1.9147|1455.1|26.977||||||||
2018/07|1 Jul 2018|Jul|2018|1.3170|1.7292|1.1267|146.83|1.3098|1.7783|10.3352|1.9390|1479.2|24.969||||||||
2018/08|1 Aug 2018|Aug|2018|1.2849|1.6791|1.1182|142.59|1.2771|1.7520|10.0874|1.9298|1446.0|24.191||||||||
2017/99||AVG|2017|1.3404|1.7118|1.1328|151.38|1.3234|1.7540|10.4727|1.9256|1453.7|25.667||||||||
2018/99||AVG|2018|1.3825|1.7180|1.1328|153.24|1.3276|1.7374|10.8108|1.9027|1474.9|26.137||||||||
```

CODE TRIED (Partially works)

```
awk ' BEGIN { OFS="|" }

{ if ($1 ~ /Jan/) $21="01" }
{ if ($1 ~ /Feb/) $21="02" }
{ if ($1 ~ /Mar/) $21="03" }
{ if ($1 ~ /Apr/) $21="04" }
{ if ($1 ~ /May/) $21="05" }
{ if ($1 ~ /Jun/) $21="06" }
{ if ($1 ~ /Jul/) $21="07" }
{ if ($1 ~ /Aug/) $21="08" }
{ if ($1 ~ /Sep/) $21="09" }
{ if ($1 ~ /Oct/) $21="10" }
{ if ($1 ~ /Nov/) $21="11" }
{ if ($1 ~ /Dec/) $21="12" }
{ if ($1 ~ /MMM/) $21="MM" }
###################
{ if (  !/remove1| remove2/  )  { ( MMM_YYYY = 1" "$1" "$2 )  ( YYYY_MM = $2"/"$21 ); print YYYY_MM, MMM_YYYY, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20  } }

'       fxdata         >fxdata_Processed.txt  


awk ' { sub (  /1 MMM YYYY/, "MMM YYYY" )  }1
'       fxdata_Processed.txt         >fxdata_Processed_2.txt
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is `99` in 2nd field of last 2 rows?

Comment: 99 is used to make it clear to the output-file user that it's not a real month.

Comment: Don't know how to extend the code prototype below.  Can anyone help? (or a different approach)?

Answer (score 0):

here is a prototype for you for the first fx rate, you can add the other and fix the formatting...

```
$ awk -v OFS='|' '/^[A-Z][a-z][a-z]/ {sum[$2]+=$3; count[$2]++} 
                  NF>1 && $1=$1; 
                  END {for(k in sum) print k"/99","AVG",k,sum[k]/count[k]}' file

MMM|YYYY|USD/GBP|CAD/GBP|EUR/GBP|JPY/GBP|CHF/GBP|AUD/GBP|HKD/GBP|NZD/GBP|KRW/GBP|MXN/GBP
Jan|2017|1.2348|1.6288|1.1611|141.81|1.2441|1.6537|9.5778|1.7318|1457.1|26.447
Feb|2017|1.2494|1.6380|1.1732|141.08|1.2508|1.6304|9.6953|1.7283|1426.1|25.369
Mar|2017|1.2346|1.6528|1.1549|139.39|1.2365|1.6199|9.5882|1.7626|1399.4|23.802
Apr|2017|1.2644|1.7001|1.1797|139.31|1.2653|1.6791|9.8297|1.8151|1435.4|23.750
May|2017|1.2920|1.7580|1.1698|145.03|1.2752|1.7379|10.0605|1.8594|1455.2|24.247
Jun|2017|1.2806|1.7030|1.1399|142.05|1.2396|1.6940|9.9874|1.7714|1449.3|23.225
Jul|2017|1.2995|1.6488|1.1272|146.03|1.2480|1.6652|10.1480|1.7658|1471.9|23.137
Aug|2017|1.2951|1.6324|1.0963|142.18|1.2499|1.6362|10.1299|1.7740|1465.3|23.052
Sep|2017|1.3338|1.6383|1.1198|147.83|1.2843|1.6735|10.4205|1.8381|1511.3|23.785
Oct|2017|1.3200|1.6638|1.1229|149.08|1.2966|1.6953|10.3033|1.8758|1494.6|24.849
Nov|2017|1.3230|1.6893|1.1262|149.16|1.3113|1.7358|10.3270|1.9211|1455.8|25.020
Dec|2017|1.3404|1.7118|1.1328|151.38|1.3234|1.7540|10.4727|1.9256|1453.7|25.667
Jan|2018|1.3825|1.7180|1.1328|153.24|1.3276|1.7374|10.8108|1.9027|1474.9|26.137
Feb|2018|1.3962|1.7571|1.1312|150.76|1.3059|1.7748|10.9210|1.9116|1507.0|26.037
Mar|2018|1.3973|1.8070|1.1329|148.25|1.3243|1.8003|10.9564|1.9256|1497.2|26.016
Apr|2018|1.4077|1.7922|1.1468|151.49|1.3630|1.8321|11.0477|1.9432|1504.6|25.874
May|2018|1.3466|1.7335|1.1396|147.62|1.3427|1.7898|10.5694|1.9367|1450.5|26.298
Jun|2018|1.3287|1.7443|1.1380|146.26|1.3154|1.7732|10.4268|1.9147|1455.1|26.977
Jul|2018|1.3170|1.7292|1.1267|146.83|1.3098|1.7783|10.3352|1.9390|1479.2|24.969
Aug|2018|1.2849|1.6791|1.1182|142.59|1.2771|1.7520|10.0874|1.9298|1446.0|24.191
2017/99|AVG|2017|1.28897
2018/99|AVG|2018|1.35761
```

Note your average computations don't seem to be right.  For the column I computed you just used the last of 2017 and first of 2018.

Also perhaps you may need to add a better pattern, perhaps `/Jan|Feb|Mar|.../` instead of my shortcut.

Comment: Seems to mostly work.  How do I add e.g. the 2nd & 3rd of the FX's?  Not sure how to extend the code.  Thanks.